# ChartView is squeezed/deformed in ViewPager/ScrollView

Tags: java, achartengine

My app has several `Fragment`s in a `ViewPager`. One of the fragments contains a `ChartView`, and when the user swipes to move to an adjacent fragment the chart gets redrawn and squeezed instead of staying at the original width as would be expected. This also happens vertically inside a `ScrollView`.

Below are screenshots of the fragment and the fragment when it's swiped.

The `ChartView` is inside a `FrameLayout` if that makes any difference. The `FrameLayout`'s width is set to `fill_parent`. The `FrameLayout` is actually subclassed, and the `ChartView` is added programmatically, like this:

```
public FrameLayoutSubclass(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
{
    super(context, attributeSet);

    ...

    chartView = new GraphicalView(context, chart);
    addView(chartView);
}
```

Any ideas on how I can keep the chart at it's original dimensions as it gets scrolled in and out of view?

Original chart:

[image: Original chart]

Squeezed chart:

[image: Squeezed chart]

**Edit**: Dan's answer did the trick: `renderer.setInScroll(true);`

Comment: Nice screenshots. What's the name of the app?

Comment: Thanks Dan! The app is Awnry News & Weather (id=com.awnry.android.nawnry). The font is Ubuntu, not part of the app. :) It's US only, but I'm expanding to international soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas that worth trying:

- Call `renderer.setInScroll(true);` when you setup the renderer.
- Call `chartView.repaint();` after the UI has re-drawn the other components.

Comment: D'oh! I should dig deeper next time. `renderer.setInScroll(true)` did the trick. Thanks!